# Convert unsigned integer to a string whose bytes are the 256-bit (BE) representation of the integer?

Tags: javascript, node.js

> Convert unsigned integer to a string whose bytes are the 256-bit (BE) representation of the integer?

Suppose I've the integer 1832 (or 0x728 in hex). Then the result of conversion should be the string whose bytes are the 256-bit big-endian representation of the integer, i.e., `0x00 0x00 ... 0x07 0x28` (the string may contain unreadable ASCII characters).

I need this, because my web API should return the result of arithmetic operation in 256-bit binary form.

Any ideas for doing this efficiently in JavaScript/Nodejs?

Comment: Are you trying to encrypt the string for delivery? for example aes256 encryption

Comment: No, I want to deliver the string to an Ethereum contract such that the contract is able to efficiently "unpack" the string to get the results.

Comment: Does [this](http://techforb.blogspot.co.uk/2007/10/how-to-convert-integer-to-little-endian.html) post help?

Comment: except it is C and not JavaScript :(

Answer (score 1):

The following is another implementation for converting a 32-bit JavaScript integer into 256-bit BE form:

```
function intTo256BigEndianString(n) {
    var result = "";

    for (var i = 0; i < 28; i++) {
        result += String.fromCharCode(0x00);
    }

    result += String.fromCharCode((n >> 24) & 0xFF);
    result += String.fromCharCode((n >> 16) & 0xFF);
    result += String.fromCharCode((n >> 8) & 0xFF);
    result += String.fromCharCode((n >> 0) & 0xFF);

    return result;
}
```

It basically, just returns a string whose characters are the bytes of the integer.

Answer (score 0):

Javascript integers can be represented as 32bits. We just need to read them as 8bit sequences and convert them to a string:

```
function intToBE(int){
 return [
   int >> 24,
   (int >> 16) & 0b11111111,
   (int >> 8) & 0b11111111,
   int & 0b11111111
 ].reduce((s,n) => s+("0"+n).substr(-2),"");
}
```

(This reduce construct is just neccessary for adding the right number of 0s)

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/mivoqupaza/edit?console)

Doing the whole thing in a loop:

```
function intToBE(int){
  var res = "";
  for(var i = 3; i >= 0; i--){
    res += ("0"+ ((int >> i*8) & 0b11111111)).substr(-2);
  }
  return res;
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/bizubaneqo/edit?js)

Since ES6 there are typed arrays which are perfect for such a conversion:

```
function intToBE(int){   
   return 
     new Uint8Array( 
        new Uint32Array([int]).buffer
     ).reduceRight(
        (r,c)=>r+("0"+c).substr(-2)
        ,""
     );
}
```

[Try it](http://jsbin.com/kocolugoli/edit?js)

Answer (score 0):

Take the code below:

```
let o = parseInt(1832).toString(2);
let arr = [];
for(let i=0;i<256-o.length;i++)
{
    arr.push(0)
}
let b = arr.join("")+o;
let j=0;
let k=j+8;
let arr2 = [];
while (k<256)
{
    let temp = b.slice(j,k);
    let temp1 = parseInt(temp,2).toString(16);
    (temp1.length==1)&&(temp1='0'+temp1);
    arr2.push('0x'+temp1);
    j=k;
    k=j+8;
}
console.log(arr2.join(" "));
```

that return `0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x00 0x07`